# How to eliminate an element inside a list in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lenght 30 (all characters). However, elements 5 and 6 have two strings. I need to eliminate one of the two strings.

I can remove the whole element but not just one of the characters in row 5 and 6.

Here is the result of my list. I need to eliminate "Plinio Apuleyo Mendoza" and "Alvaro Sierra Restrepo" so every element in the list is a character = 1

```
List of 30
 $ : chr "Álvaro Sierra Restrepo"
 $ : chr " SERGIO GÓMEZ MASERI"
 $ : chr "Redacción EL TIEMPO"
 $ : chr "Redacción EL TIEMPO"
 $ : chr [1:2] "Plinio Apuleyo Mendoza" "Plinio Apuleyo Mendoza"
 $ : chr [1:2] "Álvaro Sierra Restrepo" "Álvaro Sierra Restrepo"
```

All this because I need to convert the list into a dataframe and then combine that dataframe with another one of 30 rows. Here is the error when I try to conver it. Thanks a lot!

```
In matrix(unlist(author_articles_p), nrow = length(author_articles_p),  :
  data length [32] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [30]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example showed, the elements are `duplicated`.  In that case, just loop through the `list` and apply `unique`

```
author_articles_p1 <- lapply(author_articles_p, unique)
```

If the elements are not unique, but wanted the first element, then

```
lapply(author_articles_p, `[`, 1)
```

Then do `unlist` and create a `matrix` by specifying the `nrow/ncol` which is a multiple of the `length` of the `list`

```
matrix(unlist(author_articles_p1))
```

---

Or we can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_chr(author_articles_p, unique)
```